# Perplexing image loading error for a freshly uploaded Web site

Tags: php, html, image

I custom-coded a simple Web site, that has png images in a folder called "images/" and then uploaded it to my server. When developing the Web site on my local system, all images load and display just fine. They are links, so clicking them opens the linked image appropriately.

However, when I upload the site to my Web server and try to run it from there, the entire thing works as expected, except for some images, which look like the following (in Safari, though the behavior is the same with other browsers):

[image]

The three missing images are in the same folder, in the same format, and are basically just copies of the code that is showing the working images. There are simply no errors in the development console for either Safari, or Firefox. Furthermore, when I click the working images, then they open in a new window as expected (the anchor code targets _new); however, if I click one of the missing images, then a new window opens, but it loads the entire site again. In this new window, this time NONE of the images load in the new window. The url when hovering the mouse over the faulty images is something like the following:

http://url.example.com/images/imagename.png

This appears correct, and is similar to the URL for the working images (with different names, etc.). When the working image is clicked, then the image loads accordingly, instead of the entire site loading again in the new window.

I don't have a clue as to what might be the issue here. The lack of any sort of developer console messages is very odd. This site is coded with php and some javascript, but the code for these images are all straight HTML, such as the following (only file names are different):

```
<a href="images/fabrication.png" target="_new" title="Fabrication of instrumentation">
<figure>
    <img src="images/fabricationthumb.png" onmouseover="highlightimageon(this)" onmouseout="highlightimageoff(this)">
    <figcaption>
        Make It
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
```

All images are pngs, and were processed in the same editing program (Apple's Preview editor in OS X), and are given the same permissions (0644) on the server (did a chmod on the entire images/ folder).

UPDATE:

Here is the code for one of the non-working images:

```
<a href="images/analysiscode.png" target="_new">
<figure>
    <img src="images/analysiscodethumb.png" onmouseover="highlightimageon(this)" onmouseout="highlightimageoff(this)">
    <figcaption>
        Code it
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
```

Comment: You showed a link that is working, try adding one for us to see that is not working

Comment: @RiggsFolly, ok, I updated the posting to add the code. It's identical except for the name of the file. These two files are both in the same "images" folder. I've tried re-uploading them, and accessing them directly by typing in the URL manually, but the same behavior occurs.

Comment: What are the names of these images, is the local machine windows and the server linux.  Linux is case sensitive.  Cassing is a common issue going from windows to linux environments.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, That was was it! Ugh! OS X's HFS is case insensitive, and upon checking the server is a case-sensitive linux system. These files had the first letters capitalized. *smacks forehead*

Comment: @Topher - happens to the best of us.  Why do you think I thought to ask that one?  Not like It never stumped me before >>cough<<